# why Firebase remote push notification doesnt work in ios, but work in android

Tags: xcode, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I set configuration to get remote push notification via react-native-firebase.In android, all things are correct, but in ios, I can get FCMToken, but I can not able to receive pop up push notification.
podFile is:

```
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Auth'
 pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
 pod 'GoogleIDFASupport'
```

my AppDelegate.m is:

```
    #import <Firebase.h>
    #import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"
    #import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"
    ...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  [RNFirebaseNotifications configure];
...
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
```

and my code for get FCm token and show is:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
      'insider',
      'insider channel',
      firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max,
    );
    firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
    this.checkPermission();
    this.createNotificationListeners();
  }

  async getToken() {
    let tokenFCM = await AsyncStorage.getItem('tokenFCM');
    console.log(tokenFCM);

    if (!tokenFCM) {
      // console.log('token not find');
      try {
        tokenFCM = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
        if (tokenFCM) {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('tokenFCM', tokenFCM);
          // do sth here
        }
      } catch {
         console.log('token not find2');

      }
    } else {
      // console.log('token is find');
    }
  }

  async checkPermission() {
    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    if (enabled) {
      this.getToken();
    } else {
      this.requestPermission();
    }
  }

  async requestPermission() {
    try {
      await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
      this.getToken();
    } catch (error) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('tokenFCM', '');
      console.log('permission rejected');
    }
  }

  createNotificationListeners() {
    firebase.notifications().onNotification(notification => {
      notification.android.setChannelId('insider').setSound('default');
      notification.android.setSmallIcon('@mipmap/...');
      firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
    });
  }
```

why I can see push notification in Android but not display in ios?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I do not have error, but I can not receive any notification. Should I create developer account?

Comment: have you tried my solution? and yes you need a developer account

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding [react-native-permissions](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions) .

```
import {requestNotifications} from 'react-native-permissions';
```

and while checking permissions do this ,

```
await requestNotifications(['alert', 'badge', 'sound']);
```

Youll start getting push notifications

Hope it help. feel . free for doubts